# Unblock row editing on WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have validation in `DataGrid`. I am copying and trying to paste multiple rows. But if there is a validation error in one of the rows on insertion, the validation will will be called in and disable editing of the other rows, therefore next rows will not be inserted.

**My ValidationRule:**

```
public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        MyModel myModel = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as MyModel ;

        if (myModel.Top > myModel.Bottom)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Error!");
        }

        
        return new ValidationResult(true,null);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
       <MyValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

The paste code:

```
 protected virtual void OnExecutedPaste(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
            {
                if (ExecutePasteEvent != null)
                {
                    ExecutePasteEvent(target, args);
                    if (args.Handled)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
    
                List<string[]> clipboardData = Clipboard

    Helper2.ParseClipboardData();
                    
        
                    int minRowIndex = Items.Count;
                    int maxRowIndex = Items.Count;
                    int minColumn = 0;
        
                    if (SelectedCells.Any())
                    {
                        minRowIndex = SelectedCells.Min(g=> Items.IndexOf(g.Item));
                        maxRowIndex = Items.Count;
                        minColumn = SelectedCells.Min(g=> g.Column.DisplayIndex);
                    }
        
                    int minColumnDisplayIndex = (SelectionUnit != DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow) ? minColumn : 0;
                    int maxColumnDisplayIndex = Columns.Count - 1;
        
                    int rowDataIndex = 0;
                    List<Tuple<int, int>> cellsToSelect = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
                    for (int i = minRowIndex; i <= maxRowIndex && rowDataIndex < clipboardData.Count; i++, rowDataIndex++)
                    {
                        if (i == maxRowIndex)
                        {
                            if (!CanUserPasteToNewRows)
                                continue;
        
                            ICollectionView cv = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);
                            IEditableCollectionView iecv = cv as IEditableCollectionView;
        
                            if (iecv != null)
                            {
                                if (minRowIndex + clipboardData.Count > Items.Count)
                                {
                                    iecv.AddNew();
                                    if (rowDataIndex < clipboardData.Count)
                                    {
                                        maxRowIndex = Items.Count;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
        
                        if (i < Items.Count)
                        {
                            CurrentItem = Items[i];
        
                            BeginEditCommand.Execute(null, this);
        
                            int clipboardColumnIndex = 0;
                            for (int j = minColumnDisplayIndex; clipboardColumnIndex < clipboardData[rowDataIndex].Length; j++, clipboardColumnIndex++)
                            {
                                
                                DataGridColumn column = null;
                                foreach (DataGridColumn columnIter in this.Columns)
                                {
                                    if (columnIter.DisplayIndex == j)
                                    {
                                        column = columnIter;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
        
                                column?.OnPastingCellClipboardContent(Items[i], clipboardData[rowDataIndex][clipboardColumnIndex]);
        
                                cellsToSelect.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
                            }
        
                            CommitEditCommand.Execute(this, this);
                           
        
        
                        }
        
                    }
        
                    UnselectAll();
                    UnselectAllCells();
        
                    if (Items.Count < 1)
                        return;
        
                    CurrentItem = Items[minRowIndex];
        
                    if (SelectionUnit == DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow)
                    {
                        SelectedItem = Items[minRowIndex];
                    }
                    else if (SelectionUnit == DataGridSelectionUnit.CellOrRowHeader || SelectionUnit == DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell)
                    {
                        foreach(var c in cellsToSelect)
                        {
                            if(Columns.Count < c.Item1 && Columns.Count < c.Item2)
                            SelectedCells.Add(new DataGridCellInfo(Items[c.Item1], Columns[c.Item2]));
                        }
                     
                    }
                }
```

And `ClipboardHelper.ParseClipboardData();` will return a list of strings for example: {"row1", "value1", "value2"},{"row2", "value1", "value2"}.

How to paste all copied rows?
And I need to allow editing of all rows with errors, and not the last one.

Comment: Where do you copy from and how to do you paste? You are supposed to edit a cell at a time in the `DataGrid`...

Comment: Added information to the question.

Comment: @Natxo, No, I had to make a custom implementation.